# reset user lockout by sending a reset account link using asp net identity 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP MVC project in which I want to send an unlock account lockout link to the user's email after the user gets lockout.I use asp net identity 2.1 in my project. What i could possibly do is to lock the account for a period of 30 minutes using asp identity. After this time the account gets unlocked. I tried to send email to the user which contains a reset link. The link calls a method which has the following code.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> UnlockAccount(string userId)
{
    await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(userId);
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

But after this still my account is locked for the time period of 30 minutes which i setup in IdentityConfig.cs. Is this possible in asp net identity.

Comment: What does `.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync()` do?.

Comment: It resets the no of attempts left for the user to login before lockout

Comment: But it doesn't unlock an account, so if an account is already locked, even a gazillion attempts left wouldnt unlock it

Answer (score 31):

I know this is old but it's worth an answer as I've just been wondering the same myself...

The `AccessFailedCount` doesn't matter - the only thing locking the user out is the `LockoutEndDateUtc`. If the current UTC datetime is before the `LockoutEndDateUtc` then you won't be able to gain entry.

It's simple enough to reset though:

```
await UserManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(userId, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow));
```

You can set the `DateTimeOffset` to anything you want as long as it's before the current DateTimeUTC, in my example I use `DateTime.UtcNow` as it gives the added benefit of knowing when the account was unlocked.

When the user eventually logs in again the `AccessFailedCount` will be reset to 0, so you don't need to worry about resetting that.

Comment: Or for Core 2.0:
   await _userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, null);
Where "user" is:
 ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

Comment: still a good idea to clear the AccessFailedCount just in case the user typed a wrong password on the first try and got locked out again right after resetting password.

Comment: Why set lock out end date to today when null will work? If you set it to a date and show the lock out end date in your admin, it will have a date, and may be confusing.

Comment: @Dave I explained this in the answer - "it gives the added benefit of knowing when the account was unlocked" - I also stated that is can be set to anything you want - so it's purely there for info.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add an answer based on two of the comments above, as combined they seem to provide the best solution to this. I have a form in which I show a reCAPTCHA once the user is locked out, and clear the lockout if they submit the correct password along with a valid reCAPTCHA. The method I use to do the reset is below:

```
private async Task ResetLockoutIfPasswordCorrect(string username, string password)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
    {
        await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
        await _userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, null);
    }
}
```

As I say, I do guard this method with [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/).